# How to record user preference when using restful api and Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, rest, api

How can I record user preferences (eg. language) if I don't use cookies and sessions so that the default language of the website will be different for each user?

Comment: seems like you would need to store them in the user object from your server if you aren't storing them in the browser.....

Comment: @yifei3212 either you can use localStorage or go with storing it in the user table of the database

Comment: @NarenMurali Thanks mate! This is what I need to know.

Comment: @yifei3212 You're welcome!